# How SharedPreference.Editor actually work in Android?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to save some String data using `SharedPreference`.

Here is my code

```
// SAVE
SharedPreference mySharedPref = new SharedPreference("Data", 0);
mySharedPref.edit().putString("hello", "world");
mySharedPref.edit().putString("my", "code");
mySharedPref.edit().commit();

// LOAD
String str = mySharedPref.getString("hello", ""); // I expect "world"
```

But it only has an empty string!

Meanwhile,

```
SharedPreference.Editor editor = mySharedPref.edit();
editor.putString(...);
editor.commit();
```

This worked....

I thought `mySharedPref.edit()` returns a reference and makes the code above and below the same.

I am confused now. X(

Comment: `edit()` method in `SharedPreference` returns NEW INSTANCE of the `Editor` interface. I found the comment explaining it in `SharedPreferences.java` file came with sdk.

Answer (score 1):

[See this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example)

**Setting values in Preference:**

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
 editor.putString("name", "Elena");
 editor.putInt("idName", 12);
 editor.commit();
```

**Retrieve data from preference:**

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
String restoredText = prefs.getString("text", null);
if (restoredText != null) {
  String name = prefs.getString("name", "No name defined");//"No name defined" is the default value.
  int idName = prefs.getInt("idName", 0); //0 is the default value.
```

}

Answer (score 1):

in your code:

```
// SAVE
SharedPreference mySharedPref = new SharedPreference("Data", 0);
mySharedPref.edit().putString("hello", "world");
mySharedPref.edit().putString("my", "code");
mySharedPref.edit().commit();
```

You called `edit()` each time you put a String but you didn't call `commit()` after it so your changes is not saved. You should change to this:

```
// SAVE
SharedPreference mySharedPref = new SharedPreference("Data", 0);
mySharedPref.edit().putString("hello", "world")
    .putString("my", "code");
    .commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

`edit()` method in `SharedPreference` returns NEW INSTANCE of the `Editor` interface. I found the comment explaining it in `SharedPreferences.java` file came with sdk.

Any actions performed on the new instance will be independent from other instances.

In the first part of my code, by calling `edit()` multiple times, I was performing actions on each independent instance.

It was interesting to notice that `edit()` returns a new instance instead of a reference.

> /**
>        * Create a new Editor for these preferences, through which you can make
>        * modifications to the data in the preferences and atomically commit those
>        * changes back to the SharedPreferences object.
>        * 
>        *
>
> Note that you *must* call {@link Editor#commit} to have any
>        * changes you perform in the Editor actually show up in the
>        * SharedPreferences.
>        * 
>        * @return Returns a new instance of the {@link Editor} interface, allowing
>        * you to modify the values in this SharedPreferences object.
>        */
>       Editor edit();